# Math equation in latex

Tags: math-mode, equations

hello how can I write this equation in latex?

[image]

Comment: I would encourage you to learn a bit more about TeX.  The beginning steps aren't too bad.  The hardest part of this equation is probably getting the `k=1` and `n` in the right location.  If that was your problem and everything else was fine, it would have been helpful to say so when you posted your question.

Comment: @Teepeemm sorry about that I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to typeset the equation in question. The first replicates the expression in the screenshot you posted. The second uses what I would consider to be a somewhat more standard way of expressing the idea that the minimization takes place over an index `k` that belongs to the set of integers ranging from 1 to n.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'align*' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times roman fonts)

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
AB[i,j] &= \min\limits_{k=1}^n (A[i,k]+B[k,j])  \\
AB[i,j] &= \min\limits_{k\in\{1,\dots,n\}} (A[i,k]+B[k,j])
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for `\min\limits_{k=1}^n` using `\DeclareMathOperator*{\mlimi}{\min}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\mlimi}{\min}
\begin{document}
\[AB[i,j]=\mlimi_{k=1}^n (A[i,k]+B[k,j])\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to adjiust (decreasing) the upper and lower limits using `\scriptscriptstyle`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\mlimi}{\min}
\begin{document}
\[AB[i,j]=\mlimi_{\scriptscriptstyle k=1}^{\scriptscriptstyle n} (A[i,k]+B[k,j])\]
\end{document}
```

[image]